Indian Movie about two women married to same person
Many years ago as a child I saw a movie aired on a local channel that appeared to be Indian in nature. I've have been trying to identify this film as it stood out in my mind. This is what I remember.
Two women were married to a wealthy man (maybe a Raja/King). One was in love with him while the other didn't appear to be. When the man died the 'evil' wife had the second held in a place where  she (2nd wife) could watch her commit sati and be denied the same right.  She was then blinded and rescued. Her rescuer, at her request, shot the 1st wife during sati because she had panicked and was going to bring shame on herself by running from her husband's pyre.  
I need the name of this film.

Welcome to the community. Any other plot details? If you know, please also describe the approximate year you saw the movie. I hope you enjoy this place as much as I have.

This has a few plot points in common with the 1984 mini-series The Far Pavillions

Set in India
Two sisters marrying a prince
One is in love with someone else
One being shot (out of mercy) while being burned alive after her husband's death.

